# Are the titles of duplicate questions retained for search purposes?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, support

On StackExchange, do duplicate question titles appear after duplicate questions are merged? If duplicate question titles were discarded (instead of being merged or redirected to another question), they would no longer show up in the search results, which would be undesirable (because it would make it more difficult for users to find relevant information.)

Comment: Here's a scenario that I want to avoid: A user posts a good question with a name that few people will search for. Then, a duplicate question is posted, with a name that will be more likely to show up in search results. If the duplicate question were deleted, the most relevant question title would be lost, to the disadvantage of search engine users.

Comment: If one of the questions has a poor title, even before the merge, why has nobody edited it to be better?

Comment: I still want to know whether duplicate question titles are usually saved on Stackexchange.

Comment: No, if a question gets deleted, where would you expect the title to be saved? I don't think I expect the mod to decide which title is best during a merge.

Comment: I would also guess that the number of times a duplicate question has a better title than the one that already existed (and therefore had much more time to be improved by the community) is pretty small. Is this a theoretical question or have you seen this happen? Can you provide some real examples?

Comment: Usually, if the question title is considered relevant for searching, the question is *closed*, but not merged or deleted.